# Rails: unexpected eager load in has many join models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Dev environment using Rails 5.0 and Postgresql.
We have 3 models with has_many through relationship:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_campaigns
  has_many :campaigns, through: :account_campaigns

  def self.list_campaigns
    self.joins(:account_campaigns).select('accounts.id, array_agg(campaign_id) AS campaign_ids').group('accounts.id')
  end
end

class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_campaigns
  has_many :accounts, through: :account_campaigns
end

class AccountCampaign < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

And a controller with an action to get accounts with a list of campaigns in json format as an api:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Account.list_campaigns
  end
end
```

The result looked good but there were extra queries to get campaigns that we don't expect:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-22 12:06:04 +0700
Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Account Load (0.5ms)  SELECT accounts.id, array_agg(campaign_id) AS campaign_ids FROM "accounts" INNER JOIN "account_campaigns" ON "account_campaigns"."account_id" = "accounts"."id" GROUP BY accounts.id

"### extra queries here ###"
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "campaigns".id FROM "campaigns" INNER JOIN "account_campaigns" ON "campaigns"."id" = "account_campaigns"."campaign_id" WHERE "account_campaigns"."account_id" = $1  [["account_id", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "campaigns".id FROM "campaigns" INNER JOIN "account_campaigns" ON "campaigns"."id" = "account_campaigns"."campaign_id" WHERE "account_campaigns"."account_id" = $1  [["account_id", 2]]
Completed 200 OK in 100ms (Views: 57.3ms | ActiveRecord: 18.8ms)
```

Why does these extra query executed? And how to turn off eager loading for this case to optimize the performance as there will be tons of data?

Comment: here you have not used account_campaigns in query then why you used  joins(:account_campaigns)? If you want to keep join add includes(:account_campaigns) or add reference(:account_campaigns).

Comment: We used joins for the array_agg of campaign_id as you can see in the self.list_campaigns function. And afaik, joins is better in performance than includes. We found the reason of the eager load, I will post it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that the eager load was triggered by the render json in the controller. And that the column campaign_ids which was labeled in the select statement was used to eager load. To fix, we replace the query:

```
self.joins(:account_campaigns).select('accounts.id, array_agg(campaign_id) AS campaign_ids').group('accounts.id')
```

by:

```
self.joins(:account_campaigns).select('accounts.id, array_agg(campaign_id) AS cids').group('accounts.id')
```

The only difference is the label campaign_ids was changed to cids (or anything different from campaign_ids) to avoid the eager load to run.